# image width * height (total size larger than 40000) in jquery. that is not inside a table

Tags: jquery

```
$("img").load(function(){
  var width = $(this).width();
  var height = $(this).height();
    if (width * height > 40000) {

}});
```

I have this code, and I want to highlight an image that is larger than 40,000 pixels and if it is not inside a table. I know that using has() only gets descendants. would using load(function() be incorrect here?

Comment: you want to select images with more than 40k pixels?

Comment: In this code, you still need to determine whether or not the image has an ancestor that's a table, correct? And that's what you're asking how to do? There's nothing wrong with using the load function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to select elements, you could use selectors:

```
$images = $('img:area(40000)').not('table *');
```

Of course, you ought to be asking, wtf is `:area(40000)`?

Here you go:

```
$.expr[':'].area = function(element, index, meta, stack){
  var $ele,
    size,
    area;
  $ele = $(element);
  size = parseInt( meta[3] );
  area = $ele.width() * $ele.height();
  return area > size;
};
```

With a little more time you could extend the custom selector to take a second param so that you could use `>`, `<`, `==`, etc in a `:area(40000,lt)` style syntax.

Comment: I was about to suggest a custom selector.  +1 for being awesome and thinking about this properly.

Comment: @Levi Morrison, I love getting +1 for awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can check its `parents`:

```
if($(this).parents('table').length > 0) {/*in a table*/}
```

So in your code:

```
$("img").load(function () {
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();
    if (width * height > 40000) {
        if ($(this).parents('table').length > 0) { 
           /* in a table */
        }
        else { 
           /* NOT in a table */
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is: "How to detect if an element is a children from `<table>` ?

If so, you could do it like:

```
if ( (width * height > 40000) && !($(this).closest('table').length) ) {
}
```

That would crawl up the DOM and check if there is any `<table>` node in the list of parents. If that search is not successfull, the jQuery set is empty and it's length therefore 0.